Mesh Stretching when in Posing in Sculpt Mode
I am trying to pose my model in sculpt mode (so not with weight painting + bones) and I am seeing a weird artifact when I move the model.
Here's what it looks like before:

Here's what it looks like after:

The fingers aren't masked but they seem to be pulling away. Any idea what can cause this?

hello, maybe you've masked the tips of the fingers?

I double checked and it looks like they're fine

I have solved this. It was a combination of incorrect masking (for some reason a tiny bit of the fingers were captured) and having the mirror modifier applied. Once I fixed both of those it behaved correctly.
